# How to uninstall nuget and clear corrupted entries?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, nuget

I want to install AjaxControlToolkit via nuget. But NuGet Package Manager GUI displays error as show below.

[image]

Even when I try to install a fresh copy of AjaxControlToolkit, NuGet displays message:

Failed to install or uninstall nuget package.

I checked my project and didn't find any nuget file. Where are the corrupted entries and how to repair it?

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to implement the solution suggested by @AlexandreDion ? It worked for me. Give the guy an accepted answer! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've never ran into this specific error but I'd assume it's either packages.config that is malformed (it's an XML) or a .nupkg file is corrupted.

Do you currently have packages installed ? 
- Delete the "packages" folder in your solution and packages.config (keep it elsewhere for reference, it's the lift of installed packages), then re-install your packages. Let me know how that goes.